# Statically link MySQL in C++ Project (Mac OS X, g++, Eclipse)

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse, macos

I'm getting an error while trying to include libmysqlclient in a project. I'm using Mac OS X, Eclipse CDT, g++.

The error I'm getting is `ld: library not found for -l/usr/local/mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.a`, even though I included this file by navigating to it with the finder.

Can anyone help?

[image: Here's the library, included]

[image: Here's the library path, also included]

[image: Here's the include directory]

Answer (score 0):

If the `-l` linker flag is used, the correct value is `-lmysqlclient`, which would find either `libmysqliclient.a` or `libmysqlclient.dylib` on the library search path.

To solve your problem, do one of the following:

1. Convince your IDE not to prepend `-l` to the full pathname.
2. In your IDE settings, add `/usr/local/mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64/lib` to the library search path (that's already done, as seen on the screen shots), and specify `mysqlcient` in the *Libraries* section, so `-lmysqlclient` would be passed to the linker.

Comment: That solved one problem, but it caused me another. Now, I get the error: `dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib` . Any ideas about that? Both `libmysqlclient.a` and `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` are present in the library path.

Comment: Remove the file `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` from the library path.